# Android Studio layer below each other while orientation is horizontal

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

doing this layer work and can't figure out how to put layers below ones I made when the android orientation is horizontal, it keeps pushing my layer to the outsidie I have a pics what I have done and how it has to look, if you have any ideas would be nice to hear, thank you in advance.[How it has to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30n0X.png)
      and [What I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QDQz.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView

            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="#FA0000" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="#03ED0F" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blue"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="#0027C3"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@id/blue"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="#000000" />




    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use weight sum to equally distrubute views width ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using 
you should use these attribute to control the position

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf
app:layout_constraintTop_toStartOf
app:layout_constraintTop_toRightOf
```

based on what it should look like, you can try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#FA0000" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#03ED0F" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#0027C3"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FA0000" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#03ED0F" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0027C3"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

it should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 seperate LinearLayout one below other in root. 
One for horigontal views. Second for vertical views.
And use `weight_sum` property in LinearLayout, along with `weight` property in child views to distribute child views eqally.

Comment: And better approach is to use Relative layout to hold all child views in a single parent Layout.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that one as well, need to do different variations.